# Batch script to launch MobaXterm with several tabs

Tags: batch-file, ssh

I'm pretty new to batch so I'd appreciate the help.

The goal is to launch MobaXterm with X SSH sessions, all on the same window (different tabs).

This is the relevant part from the code:

```
set n=0
for %%a in (%name%) do (
    set n+=1
    set "name[!n!]=%%~a"
    start MobaXterm_Professional_9.1.exe -newtab -exec "waitforX; ssh -i %key% %user%@%%~a"
    ECHO name is %%~a
    timeout /t 5
)
```

With this I am able to open the first ssh session but for the rest of the sessions I get an error in each session saying "**/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument**"
If I remove "start" and "timeout" only the first session is opened because the ssh doesn't run in the background.

Comment: Try `start "" MobaXterm...`

Comment: first session is good but again for the other sessions i get the same error /bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with knowing how to use the software, which means it is not a coding issue and does not belong on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the `start` command. We have no clue as to the contents of `name` and `name` appears to play no part in the `start` operation. your code should take the elements of `name` and record them in `name[1]..name[n]` for no discernable purpose. Need more info...

Comment: @Magoo 'name' is the ip address / DNS I am trying to connect to via ssh and its value is received by %%a.
So i think %%~a has the same value of name[n]

Comment: Undoubtedly. Without a clue as to the typical contents of `name`, we can't simulate the data with which you are dealing. If the *actual* data is sensitive, just substitute 0 for a numeric and x for an alphabetic. When you `echo`ed the `start` command, was there anything different about the first `start` and the others? Only uou can tell us these things - we can't see over your shoulder!

Comment: nothing sensitive, i'll try to elaborate a bit more.

`set /P "name=Enter all DNS names you wish to connect to, separated by a space ' ': "

set n=0
for %%i in (%name%) do (
 set n+=1
 set "name[!n!]=%%~i"
 echo %%~i|findstr somestring >nul 2>&1 
 if errorlevel 1 (
  echo %%~i is not a valid DNS name, name should contain somestring
 )`

This is the part where name is read from the user input, can be anything like test.123.com

Comment: @Magoo is more information required?

Comment: Ah - I see it now. `set n+=1` is a string-set that will establish a variable named `n+` with a value of `1`. You need `set /a n+=1`

Comment: it looks like when I use `start "" MobaXterm_Professional_9.1.exe -exec "waitforX; ssh -i %key% %user%@%%~a"` instead of `start "" MobaXterm_Professional_9.1.exe -newtab -exec "waitforX; ssh -i %key% %user%@%%~a"` all sessions are working.
It looks like a problem with the -newtab  flag.

The problem is that if I don't use this flag, I get n different windows, one for each session.

Comment: It appears that newtab and exec command lines should not be used at the same time.

So syntax is `start MobaXterm_Professional_9.1.exe -newtab "waitforX; ssh -i %key% %user%@%%~a"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newtab and exec command lines should not be used at the same time. So syntax is 
`start MobaXterm_Professional_9.1.exe -newtab "waitforX; ssh -i %key% %user%@%%~a"` works.